# Django how to write query for get current logged in user email?

Tags: django

I have abstract user model. I am using this queryset for getting current logged in user username.

`currentuser_username = UserManagement.objects.filter(username=request.user)`

my terminal result:

[image]

I am not understanding how to write queryset for get current user email. If I don't know the username of current user then I can write this queryset `currentuser_username = UserManagement.objects.filter(username=request.user)` and it will give me the username of current user. How to apply same method for getting mail for current user???

here my **models.py**

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried this  `user_email = UserManagement.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)` but getting just username instead of email

[image]

Comment: `request.user.email`?...

Comment: abdul-aziz-barkat should I use `request.user.email` for get user mail ???

Comment: abdul-aziz-barkat I tried this  `user_email = UserManagement.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)` but getting just username instead of email

Comment: It will return you query_set of user objects with that email

Comment: `user_email = UserManagement.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)[0].email` or use only `user_email = request.user.email`

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem... You're not getting a username, you're getting a Queryset with the UserManagement objects retrieved in it. You still need a few more steps to obtain the username: either choose the wanted object in the queryset and get the username `queryset[0].username`, or using `user_management = UserManagement.objects.get()`, if the email is unique (it should be), and then `user_management.username`

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an solution. As I am using AbstractUser model and extending custom model based on user type so I need to be use queryset from my custom model. Which will be something like this:

`currentuser_details = Subscriber.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

then pass the currentuser_details through context to my html

```
{%for i in currentuser_details%}
    {{i.user.email}}
    {{i.user.username}}
 {%endfor%}
```

my **Subscriber model**:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(UserManagement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=1000)
```

here is  queryset for get user details from AbstractUser model:
`currentuser_details = UserManagement.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

then pass the context in views and render html template same as above.